# with bundler install --deployment do i put the files in git?

Tags: ruby, git, version-control, rubygems, bundler

So I understand that if i run bundler install --deployment it puts the gems in the vendor folder in my application, which is useful for things like shared hosting where I can't install system wide gems.  My question is, should I put this folder into source control (git), or does bundler need to install the gems on different systems, say if we're developing on a mac and deploying to linux?

Thanks!
Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put your bundler directory into source control.  You should use a shared server directory to store the bundle data.

If you're using capistrano, use the built-in bundler capistrano tasks:

(in your config/deploy.rb):

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

If not, you should create a shared bundle directory that persists between different releases, ie: /data/project/shared/bundle

```
bundle install --deployment --path /data/project/shared/bundle
```

EDIT: There should be one bundle directory for each codebase/project, not shared between projects.  For example, each capistrano deploy directory has it's own shared area which is shared between releases, but not between deployed apps/codebases.

Comment: well i don't want to share gems between projects.  I want them specific to each site.  Can i still do that?

Comment: Absolutely.  Sorry if I wasn't clear, but that is what I was recommending.  Edited answer to clarify that.

Comment: sweet.  thanks! I was thinking of using the capistrano shared dir precisely.

Comment: ok, ran into an issue.  

I deployed a rails site with the require statement you mentioned.  It failed, despite the fact that a normal bundler install works and ssh'ing out to the server and doing bundler install --deployment also works.  Here's the error:

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'

Comment: It looks like it's failing to compile a native extension for a gem.  Which gem is producing the error? You're likely missing build tools or dev libraries.

Comment: its the json gem, which does have native libraries.  however, it runs fine under the same login if i run bundle install --deployment manually.  So i'm not sure whats missing since I'm running it both ways on the same machine.